# How to access element in a template (Blaze - Meteor)

Tags: meteor, coffeescript, meteor-blaze

I have a template:

```
<template name="example">
    <div class="target"></div>
</template>
```

I want to select the .target element (in coffeescript):

```
Template.example.rendered = ->
    $target = $(".target")
```

I could do this. But, it will look in the whole html document. I want to search only in the template. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In coffee:

```
Template.example.rendered = ->
  $target = @$('.target')
```

### In javascript:

```
Template.example.rendered = function() {
  var $target = this.$('.target');
};
```

In Meteor `1.0.4.2` and later, `template.rendered` is deprecated. Use `onRendered` instead.

### In coffee:

```
Template.example.onRendered ->
  $target = @$('.target')
```

### In javascript:

```
Template.example.onRendered(function() {
  var $target = this.$('.target');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for deprecation notice, I'm learning right now and this explains a bit more!